# How to remove module.exports with esbuild to prevent "module is not defined" error in browser?

Tags: javascript, esbuild

I have a simple JavaScript class I run tests against with Jest. Here's a greatly simplified version of it.

```js
class MyFormatter {
  formatText(str){
    return 'foo ' + str
  }
}

module.exports = MyFormatter;
```

In jest I can import it with `require` and run my tests. It all works great.

```js
const MyFormatter = require("./my-formatter");
let mf = new MyFormatter()
//etc...
```

---

Now I want to use this class in a simple static browser-based project. I have tried using esbuild to minify and place the generated file in my web project folder

```txt
esbuild lib/my-formatter.js --minify --outfile=web/my-formatter.min.js
```

I include both the newly generated/minified file in my document

```html
<script src="my-formatter.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

and then within `script.js` I can just call `new MyFormatter()` since it's in the global namespace.

This works but I get this console error

```txt
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
```

due to the `module.exports` that is left in the minified file.

Is there a way to remove this with esbuild so that I don't get a console error? Am I thinking about this the wrong way and is there something else I should be doing instead?

---

I have tried adding the `--bundle` flag as well, but that wraps everything in an anonymous function and I lose class name in the global namespace. the output file becomes

```js
(() => {
    var u = (i, e) => () => (
        e || i((e = { exports: {} }).exports, e), e.exports
    );
    var f = u((c, l) => {
        var s = class {
          //... my code is here
        };
        l.exports = s;
    });
    f();
})();
```

Which is unusable to me from the other script file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did that worked. Since I have `lib/my-formatter.js` which contains my library and `web/script.js` where I want to use it.

Within `web/script.js` I simply require the library and use it normally

```js
const MyFormatter = require("../lib/my-formatter");
const my = new MyFormatter();
```

Now I instead create a bundle from **THIS** file instead of the library

```
esbuild web/script.js --bundle --minify --outfile=web/script.min.js
```

Now I just link to this bundled file: `<script src="script.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Include the `--bundle` flag

```
esbuild lib/my-formatter.js --bundle --minify --outfile=web/my-formatter.min.js
```

https://esbuild.github.io/getting-started/#bundling-for-the-browser

Comment: I have tried this but then I lose the variable name due to minification and the anonymous function wrapper. The output file becomes `(() => { var a=b((c)=>{ ... }); a(); })();` How can I then access my class from another script file?